# Daily reward help, Discord Bot

Tags: python, clock, counting, discord.py

I am writing a discord bot, I want players to earn a daily reward, however I am not sure how I can allow the user to receive their reward every 24+hrs. I have tried many solutions but have come up with none.

(Rewrite, EXT)

**Points to  note:**

1. The bot will use json files to store the time in which the user
   claimed their daily bonus.
2. There will be many users executing this pretty much at the same time so the feature must be able to be used by multiple people.

Thanks to anyone who helps, even if it isn't too helpful.

Comment: Do you have a starting point? Perhaps a bot already in use? Which python library are you using to connect to discord? We can't help without these pieces of information

Comment: I do have my bot working already, I just want to add the daily feature, I forgot to mention, I believe I am using Rewrite with EXT.

Comment: "will use json files" - this is not very concurrency-friendly. Better to use a real database.

Comment: the json files are only use to store the time while the bot is down, once the bot is up it will store time in a dict along with the user id and balance.

Comment: @Speketwome You're on the right path: some kind of key-value storage is needed here (such as python's dicts). What _exactly_ are you having problems with?

Comment: @Segio Tulentsev  need to store the time they claimed their bonus and then count on 24hrs, but this will have to be done for lots of users all concurrently. Once the users claim is 24+hrs old they may claim it again.

Comment: @Speketwome: yes, that's requirements. Have you tried implementing them? If yes, where are you stuck? If not, why?

Comment: I have no idea where to start, hence why I came here to see if anyone else had an answer I could develop on

Comment: @Speketwome: but you have it already. Just store the last time in a dict, keyed by user id. Then just check this timestamp against current time to see if user is eligible for a reward. JFYI, you should `@mention` people if you're replying to someone and want them to see your comments.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Understood but that means the user will only be able to claim the reward when it is the same time. I want them to be able to claim the reward 24hrs or more.

Comment: @Speketwome: then just code it so. In ruby we'd do something like `if last_reward_at < Time.now - 24.hours`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The reason I came here was to find out how I could code it, I have no idea how to... (I know how to code python)

Comment: @Speketwome: you don't know how to code in python a comparison between two timestamps and/or adding/subtracting two times? I don't either. I could google it, but my googling is as good as yours.

Comment: I think I might've just thought of something

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Hhm, it's not just as easy as comparing the two numbers. I need to be able to workout if the diference between them is 24 or more hours

Comment: @Speketwome: this sounds like a very googlable question :)

Comment: I had a brainwave! I fixed this problem by using the Unix epoch time format. Basically I took the current time and minus the time stored in the dict. If the difference is more or equal to 86400 seconds then a day has passed, allowing them to reclaim their bonus

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed this problem by using the Unix epoch time format. Basically I took the current time and minus the time stored in the dict. If the difference is more or equal to 86400 seconds then a day has passed, allowing them to reclaim their bonus**